# How to re-apply bindings after clear a node on Knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm unable to apply bindings even after clearing node on Knockout. I'm trying to use components dynamically based on user actions (click a button, etc).

I created a UIComponent class to handle components, creating and removing them:

```
    (function (window) {

      define(['knockout'], function (ko) {

        /**
         * Custom component to the given DOM node
         * @type {{render: UIComponent.render}}
         */
        var UIComponent = (function () {

            return {

                /**
                 *  Render a component
                 * @param {object} component
                 * @param {object} element
                 */
                render: function (component, element, childComponents) {

                    var tagName = element.tagName && element.tagName.toLowerCase();

                    if (ko.components.isRegistered(tagName)) {
                        ko.components.unregister(tagName);
                    }

                    if (undefined !== childComponents) {

                        childComponents.forEach(function (child) {

                            if (ko.components.isRegistered(child.tagName)) {
                                ko.components.unregister(child.tagName);
                            }

                            ko.components.register(child.tagName, child.component);
                        });
                    }

                    ko.components.register(tagName, component);
                    ko.applyBindings();
                },

                /**
                 * Removes a component
                 * @param {object} component
                 * @param {object} element
                 */
                remove: function (component, element) {

                    ko.components.unregister(component.name);
                    ko.cleanNode(element);

                    // Remove any child elements from node
                    while (element.firstChild) {
                        element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
                    }
                }
            };

        })();

        window.UIComponent = UIComponent;

        return UIComponent;
    });
})(window);
```

I'm using RequireJS to load files for components dynamically, so I declare a component with an object containing a javascript file for viewModel and a template:

```
var QuoteForm = {
        viewModel: {
            require: '/scripts/components/sample-form.js'
        },
        template: {
            require: 'text!/templates/forms/available-products-quote-form.html'
        }
    };
```

And I use this component object on UIComponent class like this:

```
UIComponent.render(QuoteForm, $('quote-form')[0]);
```

This is the viewModel inside **sample-form.js** file:

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {

    var SampleFormModel = function (params) {

    };

    SampleFormModel.prototype = {

        /**
         * Dispose any resources used on component
         */
        dispose: function () {
            console.log('SampleFormModel disposed');
        }
    };

    return SampleFormModel;
});
```

To test, I'm using a simple `setTimeout` function to simulate user action:

```
UIComponent.render(QuoteForm, $('quote-form')[0]);

setTimeout(function () {
  UIComponent.remove(QuoteForm, $('quote-form')[0]);
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function () {
  UIComponent.render(QuoteForm, $('quote-form')[0]);
}, 4000);
```

When the first `setTimeout` executes, I got the `SampleFormModel disposed` message logged on console, but when the second `setTimeout` executes, I got an error from Knockout:

`Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.`

Even when Knockout disposes the component, I can't apply the bindings on the same node again.

Comment: You are calling `ko.applyBindings();` with no argument, so it applies to the entire DOM tree. You are cleaning only a particular node. I'm pretty sure you're doing things by hand that ko.components would take care of for you. You shouldn't need to use `cleanNode` at all.

Comment: WOW! It did the trick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [Roy J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392102/roy-j) said, I was applying the bindings to entire DOM. I just made some changes to `UIComponent` class just to register components to specific element:

```
(function (window) {

    define(['knockout'], function (ko) {

        /**
         * Custom component to the given DOM node
         * @type {{render: UIComponent.render}}
         */
        var UIComponent = (function () {

            return {

                /**
                 *  Render a component
                 * @param {object} component
                 * @param {object} element
                 */
                render: function (component, element, childComponents) {

                    var tagName = element.tagName && element.tagName.toLowerCase();

                    if (undefined !== childComponents) {

                        childComponents.forEach(function (child) {
                            ko.components.register(child.tagName, child.component);
                        });
                    }

                    ko.components.register(tagName, component);
                    ko.applyBindings(component, element);
                },

                /**
                 * Removes a component
                 * @param {object} component
                 * @param {object} element
                 */
                remove: function (component, element) {

                    ko.components.unregister(component.name);
                    ko.cleanNode(element);

                    // Remove any child elements from node
                    while (element.firstChild) {
                        element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
                    }
                }
            };

        })();

        window.UIComponent = UIComponent;

        return UIComponent;
    });

})(window);
```

Now it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You, need to clean your element before applying a binding on the same element, so, You can clean the element by using

```
ko.cleanNode(element)
```

This function will remove all the binding from the node on which you want to reapply the binding.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm using this function on `remove` method on my Component class but still having the error message.

Comment: sorry, I didn't noticed.

Comment: No problem. Thank you, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar yet with Knockout Components but I've been looking at the documentation.

There's this one tidbit here:

> If you want all instances of your component to share the same viewmodel object instance (which is not usually desirable)...it’s necessary to specify viewModel: { instance: object }, and not just viewModel: object.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#registering-components-as-a-viewmodeltemplate-pair

Looking at your code, you essentially have multiple instances of the HTML component (by rendering twice), but you are reusing the viewmodel.  Have you tried this:

```
var QuoteForm = {
    viewModel: {
        instance: { require: '/scripts/components/sample-form.js' }
    },
    template: {
        require: 'text!/templates/forms/available-products-quote-form.html'
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It doesn't work. RequireJS didn't load the **sample-form.js** file. Knockout's docs is pretty lack of information regarding to AMD integration.

Comment: Try instead in sample-form.js doing return { instance: new SampleFormModel() };